# Symfony 3 usar servicio dentro de otro servicio

Tags: symfony3, symfony, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Apelo al conocimieniento de la comunidad para resolver una duda sobre el uso de servicios, sobre si es factible usar las funcionalidades de un servicio dentro de otro.

Tengo dos dos servicios definidos cuya nomeclatura es la siguiente:

```
GestorSolicitudController
GestorTurnosController
```

Si en el **GestorTurnoController** , intento llamar una funcion declarada en **GestorTurnosController** de la siguiente manera:

```
$servicio = $this->container->get('gestor_solicitudes');
$solicitud = $servicio->obtenerSolicitudActual($dni);
```

Me genera el error **Call to a member function get() on null** 
Provisoriamente, lo resolvi usando inyeccion de dependencias, declarando un atributo de la siguiente forma:

```
class GestorTurnoController extends Controller
{
   protected $entityManager;
   //usamos injeccion de dependencias porque no puedo usar un servicio en otro
//to-do ver como resolverlo
protected $solicitudes;

public function __construct($entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->solicitudes = new GestorSolicitudController($entityManager);
}
```

De esta forma, funciona correctamente. Pero me queda la duda si es que no se puede usar un servicio dentro de otro, en caso de que sea factible me puedan indicar como y en caso de no serlo, lo resuelto con inyeccion de dependencias. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi el problema con un concepto que es nueva para mi: **inyección de servicios**

Googleando encontre las siguientes referencias de symfony 2.x
[enlace](https://librosweb.es/libro/symfony_2_x/capitulo_16/inyectando_servicios.html) [enlace2](https://openwebinars.net/blog/symfony2-tutorial-servicios-e-inyeccion-de-dependencias/)
Donde explican el uso de inyeccion de un servicio dentro de otro.

En mi caso, modifique el archivo *services.yml* de la siguiente forma:

```
    gestor_turnos:
    class: ComensalesBundle\Servicios\GestorTurnoController
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager","@gestor_solicitudes"]
    public: true
```

Se incorporo el argumento **@gestor_solicitudes** que hace referencia al otro servicio que me interesa usar.

En el controlador, modifique el constructor de la siguiente forma:

```
class GestorTurnoController extends Controller
{
protected $entityManager;
protected $solicitudes;

//referencia de inyeccion de dependencias
public function __construct($entityManager,$gestor_solicitudes)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->solicitudes = $gestor_solicitudes;
}
```

Ahora en los metodos que necesito acceder a una funcion del servicio inyectado, solo escribo:

```
$this->solicitudes->metodoQueQuieroUsar();
```

Espero que les sirva!

Comment: La solucion sirve para Symfony 3.x

Comment: Así es siempre que tengas declarado claro el primer servicio obviamente o la clase que quieras utilizar podrás inyectarla como servicio a otro; es justo lo que hacemos en el proyecto donde me encuentro; incluso con otros servicios transversales que usamos de otras dependencias de otras áreas...

Comment: Quiero Agregar que he visto como agregan el contenedor de servicios entero para obtener lo que necesitan de alli, a esto agrego:
* Por favor NO hacerlo, el contenedor de servicios no es un servicio que se pueda inyectar, aunque es posible; pero esto carga todos los servicios y es innecesariamente pesado; ralentiza el rendimiento del SF sobre todo en la versión 2.x
* Si tu servicio Requiere un número grande de otros servicios, piensa en dividirlo ya que seguramente estas dependiendo de muchas cosas que se pueden separar o bien podrías agregar dentro del servicio que.